# How to fill a zeros 3D array with a random number of ones specified in a 2D matrix?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

The 3D array A is of size MxNxP.
The 2d matrix B is of size MxN.
For each row of B, there is at maximum one element greater than zero.
Example:

```
B = [0 3 0; 2 0 0];
A = zeros(2,3,4);
```

I want to randomly fill A such that it has exactly three ones in the first row and second column and exactly two ones in the second row and first column. For instance:

```
A(:,:,1) = [0 1 0; 0 0 0]
A(:,:,2) = [0 1 0; 1 0 0]
A(:,:,3) = [0 0 0; 1 0 0]
A(:,:,4) = [0 1 0; 0 0 0]
```

In other words, the B elements indicate how many ones should be in the third dimension of A with the same row and column indices.
I am currently able to do it with a loop but I'm looking forward to doing it in a more efficient way, hence without a loop since M and N are really large in practice.
This is my code:

```
B = [0 3 0; 2 0 0];
A = zeros(2,3,4);
for i = 1:size(B,1)
    [r,c] = max(B(i,:));
    idx = randperm(size(A,3),r);
    A(i,c,idx) = 1;
end
```

Comment: What's your metric for "more efficient" here? Is the code slow, or do you just want fewer than 6 lines? Loops aren't inherently slow...

Comment: Yes, the code is slow since M is really large. That's why I asked for a "more efficient" solution, meaning that I wanted a solution fully exploiting MATLAB's matrix manipulations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the benchmark at the bottom of this answer to address the "efficiency" in terms of computation time.

**You can make your indexing loop faster**

By using `find`, you can get the actual indices where `B` is non-zero which makes the loop more "targeted", then you can skip the call to `max` because we don't care about the whole row of `B` either.

This is arguably more flexible too, since it doesn't assume any constraint on the number of non-zero values in each row of `B`.

```
[M, N] = size(B);
% Set up the output
A = zeros(M,N,P);
% Get row and column indices of non-zero B
[r,c] = find(B);
for ii = 1:numel(r)
    % Index into A, given row and column, random columns according to B
    A( r(ii), c(ii), randperm( P, B(r(ii), c(ii)) ) ) = 1;
end
```

**Full matrix operations are not necessarily fast**.
The below operation uses no looping, but is really memory inefficient which makes it slow for large inputs!

1. Create a random matrix

   ```
   r = rand( M, N, P );
   ```
2. Sort the random random matrix in the 3rd dimension, we don't care about the sorted matrix, just the indices; i.e. the ordering. This is a method for obtaining an entire matrix where each vector into the 3rd dimension contains `1:P` shuffled (akin to using `randperm` in a loop).

   ```
   [~,shuff] = sort(r, 3);
   ```
3. Use `B` as a threshold to convert the shuffled indices to `1`/`0`. Note that this uses implicit expansion, which requires MATLAB 2016b or newer.

   ```
   A = (shuff <= B)
   ```

You can combine 1. and 2. into a single step, so the full code becomes

```
% Inputs
B = [0 3 0; 2 0 0];
P = 4;
% Get shuffled matrix
[M, N] = size(B);
[~,shuff] = sort( rand( M, N, P ), 3 );
% Get ouput
A = (shuff <= B);
```

**Benchmark**

We can run a quick benchmark to compare these methods. At the very small end, the matrix operations are faster. For large `B`, the efficient loop proposed at the top of this answer is significantly quicker.

This benchmark uses `N = 7, P = 10, M = variable` since you said in reality your `M` is large.

[image: benchie]